# prevent click for 250ms function

Tags: jquery, function, click, delay

I have been trying to add a 250ms delay so that the function does not run twice if the element is clicked on more than once within 250ms of the first click event. HELP!

```
$(function () {
    $(".layout a").click(function () {
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel'); 
        $.cookie("Layout", $(this).attr('name'), { expires: 365, path: '/media', secure: true });
        $('.content, .searchresults').fadeOut(250, function () {     
           $("link:first").attr("href", rel); window.scrollTo(0, 0); }).delay(150).fadeIn(225); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not remove the click and then re-add it when you are done fading out:

```
$(".layout a").click(clickHandler);


function clickHandler() {
    var self = $(this)
    self.unbind('click', clickHandler);

    var rel = $(this).attr('rel'); 
    $.cookie("Layout", $(this).attr('name'), { expires: 365, path: '/media', secure: true });
    $('.content, .searchresults').fadeOut(250, function () {     
       $("link:first").attr("href", rel); 
       window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      self.click(clickHandler); }).delay(150).fadeIn(225); 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: most definitely the simplest method.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some marker (css class, custom attribute, data attribute, etc.) that shows that currently something is in process. Here is example how it could be implemented:

```
$(function () {
    $(".layout a").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);        
        if ($this.data('inprocess') == true)
            return false;

        $this.data('inprocess', true);
        window.setTimeout(function() { $this.data('inprocess', false); }, 250);


        var rel = $(this).attr('rel'); 
        $.cookie("Layout", $(this).attr('name'), { expires: 365, path: '/media', secure: true });
        $('.content, .searchresults').fadeOut(250, function () {     
           $("link:first").attr("href", rel); window.scrollTo(0, 0); }).delay(150).fadeIn(225); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the main problem is to prevent click function, while one is already running,

UPDATE: Thanks @John Koerner for finding out my code's bug. I thought accepted answer was the best approach when I saw it and upvoted it.

But here is my updated answer,

```
$.fn.onlyOneClick = function () {
    this.one("click", function () {
        var self = $(this);
        alert("clicked");
        $("div").fadeIn(1500, function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(1500, function () {
                self.onlyOneClick();
            });
        });
    });
}
$("span").onlyOneClick();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BuA8D/3/)

Comment: One problem with this approach is what if there are multiple matches to the `.layout a` selector?  You will be rebinding the same event multiple times to the ones not clicked.  http://jsfiddle.net/BuA8D/  Watch the alerts add up as you click.

Comment: @JohnKoerner, yes you're right. I've updated it, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BuA8D/3/) one seems to be working now.